# Parent Div not expanding with child Divs

Tags: html, css

I have set up a jsfiddle to demonstrate my problem. Excuse all the css as this is only one part of the screen.  The lilac background and bottom purple border should be below the final entry in the list but it does not expand correctly. I have tried all sorts of position: settings and clear settings but cannot get it to expand. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Here is the sample  http://jsfiddle.net/qwSpx/

```
<div class='innerpagerhbox'>
<div id='innerpagelatesttab'></div>
<div id='innerpageblogtabmore'><a href='#' title='more>'><img src='../content_assets/header_Latest_more.png'/></a>

</div>
<div id='innerpagelatestholder'>
    <div class='innerpageblogentry'>
        <div class='innerpageblogentryright'><a href='#'>Phishing emails test employee</a>

        </div>
        <div class='innerpageblogentryleft'></div>
        <div class='clear'></div>
    </div>
    <img src='../content_assets/RHBox_latestnews_Divider.png' alt='' />
    <div class='innerpageblogentry'>
        <div class='innerpageblogentryright'><a href='#'>UK considers prison terms for DPA breaches</a>

        </div>
        <div class='innerpageblogentryleft'></div>
        <div class='clear'></div>
    </div>
    <img src='../content_assets/RHBox_latestnews_Divider.png' alt='' />
    <div class='innerpageblogentry'>
        <div class='innerpageblogentryright'><a href='#'>Foxtons customer information hacked</a>

        </div>
        <div class='innerpageblogentryleft'></div>
        <div class='clear'></div>
    </div>
    <img src='../content_assets/RHBox_latestnews_Divider.png' alt='' />
    <div class='innerpageblogentry'>
        <div class='innerpageblogentryright'><a href='#'>Cyber-attack on employer scores own goal</a>

        </div>
        <div class='innerpageblogentryleft'></div>
        <div class='clear'></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `overflow` property in the *parent element*:

**CSS**

```
div#innerpagelatestholder {
   /* The rest of your code */
   overflow: auto;
}
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qwSpx/3/)**.

Cheers,
Leonardo

Comment: Thamks for the fast response. I really thought I had tried that ;-) will give it a shot tomorrow. The fiddle looks perfect.